# How do I fix loop time in unity even though it is enabled?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation, unity-container

When i add animation to animator in unity 2020.1.3f and i want it to be in infinite loop it pauses after one cycle knowing Loop Time is enabled

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

There is a loop function on the animation clip called loop. If you want to loop through your clip over and over, the enable it.
I don't have enough rep to post a picture yet, but here is a image of what it looks like https://www.google.com/search?q=animation+loop+feature+unity&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA845CA845&sxsrf=ALeKk008pakwg2CfVPkD2wC4hNGmselSxg:1599702152566&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=QMJ5GQP1EIIrrM%252CGBN5feXfV4TSNM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kSEHfRYMQzMoCPlbk1_12JFGtkvAQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ3LL0ut3rAhUSqZ4KHfYlDs4Q9QF6BAgMEAM#imgrc=QMJ5GQP1EIIrrM

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be after Enabling Looptime to not have clicked on apply Button.